# Centralizar Google Maps entre duas rotas Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps-javascript-api

Boa Tarde, Pessoal!

Estou enfrentando problemas para centralizar usando API Google Maps entre 2 pontos, o que acontece segue nas imagens abaixo.

A aplicação é em Ruby on Rails e usamos o JS para parte dos maps, quando clico para abrir o modal ele abre o modal com o maps só que não centraliza como pode ver nas imagens, mesmo eu usando um map.setZoom() e map.setCenter(). Segue o codigo que desenvolvi em anexo.

Desde já agradeço a ajuda!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#pipeline_modal_map_tracker").html("");
  $("#pipeline_modal_map_tracker").html("<%= j render 'pipeline_modal_map_tracker' %>");
  $("#modalPipelineMapTracker").modal("show");




 var map;
 var marker;
 var center = new google.maps.LatLng(-13.4949748,-69.825632);

 function initMap() {
   var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
   var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_pipeline2'), {
     zoom: 7
   });

   directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

   "<%= puts  @sender_location.address  + ',' +  @sender_location.address_number + ',' + @sender_location.city + ',' + @sender_location.state  %>"
   "<%= puts  @receiver_location.address  + ',' + @receiver_location.address_number  + ',' + @receiver_location.city + ',' + @receiver_location.state  %>"

    directionsService.route({
     origin:  "<%= @sender_location.address  + ',' +  @sender_location.address_number + ',' + @sender_location.city + ',' + @sender_location.state  %>" ,
     destination:  "<%=  @receiver_location.address  + ',' + @receiver_location.address_number  + ',' + @receiver_location.city + ',' + @receiver_location.state  %>" ,
     travelMode: 'DRIVING'
    }, function(response, status) {
     if (status === 'OK') {

      /*New Test God*/
      document.getElementById('map_pipeline2').className = "directions";
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      var bounds = response.routes[0].bounds;

      map.fitBounds(bounds);
      map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
      map.setZoom(6);


     } else {
            alert("");
        }
    });






 }

 $( "#modalPipelineMapTracker" ).on("shown.bs.modal", function(){
  google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
 });


 initMap();
});
```

[image: Não Centraliza][image: Centralizar 2]

Comment: `bounds.getCenter()` retorna um array ou um objeto LatLng? `map.setCenter()` precisa do objeto

Comment: Sim é um objeto LatLng. @RicardoMoraleida

Comment: No meu app eu utilizo var rendererOptions = { map: map, suppressMarkers: true }; var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions); Não tenho certeza se é isso que faltou no seu caso.

Comment: @AndréVicente testei a sua dica e sem sucesso! Mesmo assim, muito obrigado!

Comment: Dei uma pesquisada, apenas colocando directionsDisplay.setDirections(response); sem o fitBounds e setCenter deveria funcionar, não estou usando no meu código. Veja este exemplo http://www.dreamdealer.nl/tutorials/getting_directions_with_google_maps.html

Comment: Obrigado @AndréVicente, pela ajuda tudo certo!